# Is JavaFX Animation slow?

Tags: javafx

I have a simple animation consisting of resizing the stage and fading in/out on scene change.
There are two scenes `sample.fxml` and `sample2.fxml`, which are being toggled between.
Both the scenes have a single `<Button>` centered inside a `<BorderPane>` and calling the `loadScene` method.

SampleController:

```java
package sample;

import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.beans.value.WritableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Window;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SampleController {
    public BorderPane rootPane;
    double DURATION = 1000;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        rootPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: teal;");
        // Add fade in animation
        FadeTransition fadeTransitionIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(DURATION), rootPane);
        fadeTransitionIn.setFromValue(0);
        fadeTransitionIn.setToValue(1);
        fadeTransitionIn.play();
    }

    public void loadScene(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Window screen = rootPane.getScene().getWindow();
        // Add fade out animation
        FadeTransition fadeTransitionOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(DURATION), rootPane);
        fadeTransitionOut.setFromValue(1);
        fadeTransitionOut.setToValue(0);

        WritableValue<Double> writableHeight = new WritableValue<>() {
            @Override
            public Double getValue() {
                return screen.getHeight();
            }

            @Override
            public void setValue(Double value) {
                screen.setHeight(value);
            }
        };
        WritableValue<Double> writableWidth = new WritableValue<>() {
            @Override
            public Double getValue() {
                return screen.getWidth();
            }

            @Override
            public void setValue(Double value) {
                screen.setWidth(value);
            }
        };

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                        new KeyValue(writableWidth, screen.getWidth()),
                        new KeyValue(writableHeight, screen.getHeight())
                ),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(DURATION),
                        new KeyValue(writableWidth, 1000.0),
                        new KeyValue(writableHeight, 300.0)
                )
        );
        timeline.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    screen.getScene().setRoot(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample2.fxml")));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        new ParallelTransition(timeline, fadeTransitionOut).play();
    }
}
```

SampleController2:

```java
package sample;

import javafx.animation.*;
import javafx.beans.value.WritableValue;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Window;
import javafx.util.Duration;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SampleController2 {
    public BorderPane rootPane;
    double DURATION = 1000;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        rootPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue;");
        // Add fade in animation
        FadeTransition fadeTransitionIn = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(DURATION), rootPane);
        fadeTransitionIn.setFromValue(0);
        fadeTransitionIn.setToValue(1);
        fadeTransitionIn.play();
    }

    public void loadScene(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Window screen = rootPane.getScene().getWindow();
        // Add fade out animation
        FadeTransition fadeTransitionOut = new FadeTransition(Duration.millis(DURATION), rootPane);
        fadeTransitionOut.setFromValue(1);
        fadeTransitionOut.setToValue(0);

        WritableValue<Double> writableHeight = new WritableValue<>() {
            @Override
            public Double getValue() {
                return screen.getHeight();
            }

            @Override
            public void setValue(Double value) {
                screen.setHeight(value);
            }
        };
        WritableValue<Double> writableWidth = new WritableValue<>() {
            @Override
            public Double getValue() {
                return screen.getWidth();
            }

            @Override
            public void setValue(Double value) {
                screen.setWidth(value);
            }
        };

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.ZERO,
                        new KeyValue(writableWidth, screen.getWidth()),
                        new KeyValue(writableHeight, screen.getHeight())
                ),
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(DURATION),
                        new KeyValue(writableWidth, 500.0),
                        new KeyValue(writableHeight, 500.0)
                )
        );
        timeline.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                try {
                    screen.getScene().setRoot(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml")));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        new ParallelTransition(timeline, fadeTransitionOut).play();
    }
}
```

However, the animation is very choppy.

- Is JavaFX really that slow?
- Or am I doing something wrong?

---

Edit: I even removed (commented out) the fade in/out animation. It appears even just the resize animation is too slow and choppy.

Any suggestions to improve the animation performance are appreciated.

Comment: I seem to remember trying to animate the _window_ position and/or size was not smooth, at least on Windows 10. That might have something to do with how JavaFX communicates with the native window system. "Normal" animations (e.g. animating node properties) typically perform adequately.

Comment: @Slaw interesting. Maybe it is better to use a `Group` and animate the dimensions of inner nodes? I seem to remember that `Group`s resize automatically based on their components.

Comment: A `Group` will [auto-size](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#autosize()) its children when [configured to do so](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Group.html#autoSizeChildrenProperty) (which it is by default). You might be able to implement what you want (though I'm not exactly sure what the end goal is). If not, you can always create your own layout. Note that `Group` takes into account any _transformations_ applied to its children when calculating its bounds; the other layouts don't do this.